# How to combine dates by month in a pivot table in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have created the following example Google Sheet to illustrate the question,

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UIwxJe0Jww3cJYM9rpZUUI1Ppf7iSr-sOootuJJgWgQ/edit?usp=sharing

You'll see that I have date in columns with the following headers {Master Category, Subcategory,    Date,   Amount}

I put in a bunch of fake transaction dates and amounts. The dates span roughly a 6 month period of time.

The pivot table on the right is basically what I want except, I want all transactions in each month to be summed together into a single column. So, there would be 6 columns of months `{Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May}` and then one more column with a total of all 6 months.

How do I configure the Google Sheet pivot table to combine all transactions into their respective month?

Comment: Have you tried this `right-click date column` -\> `create pivot date group` -\> `select Year-Month`?

Comment: @George That did it! So easy too. I didn't know about that capability. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it worked, let me compose it as an answer. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 5):

To combine all transactions in their respective month on the pivot table you can do the following:

> - Right click on the `date column` from your existing pivot table
> - Select `Create pivot date group`
> - Select the desired date format, in your instance you can select `Year-month`

### Demo:

[image]